# Check string for array elements and systematically replace them with HTML tags - (JS, ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, reactjs

I need to search a `string`, and if it has any values that match my `array`, I need to add `<span></span>` tags to them to add custom CSS. I am using reactJS.

1. How do I search the string for objects from my array? 
   Example:

   `let string = 'this is a message with many inputs, {{input1}}, {{input2}}, and again {{input1}}'
   let array = [{parameter: '{{input1}}'},{parameter: '{{input2}}'},...]
   findAllOccurrances = () => {???}`
2. Then systematically replace them `'{{inputX}}'` with `<span className='bizarre-highlight'>{{inputX}}</span>`

My intent is to add custom CSS to any text in the div which matches my `array`, so if you got any ideas please shoot! Again, using reactJS if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a component that will replace the elements that need to be highlighted with a span you can test it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/n5vq7zjlz0)

The component is:

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ terms, children }) => {
  const result = []
  const regex = terms.map(escapeRegExp).join('|');
  const re = new RegExp(regex);
  let text = (' ' + children).slice(1); // copy
  let match = re.exec(text);
  while (match != null) {
    const str = match.toString();
    result.push(text.slice(0, match.index));
    result.push(<span className="highlighted">{str}</span>);
    text = text.slice(match.index + str.length);
    match = re.exec(text);
  }
  result.push(text);
  return result;
}

function escapeRegExp (str) {
  return str.replace(/[-[\]/{}()*+?.\\^$|]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

And you should use it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Highlighter from './Highlighter';

const terms = [ '{{input1}}', '{{input2}}' ]

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Highlighter terms={terms}>
      {'this is a message with many inputs, {{input1}}, {{input2}}, and again {{input1}}'}
    </Highlighter>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I will need check it out, but the link to it working was completely accurate! thank you!!!!

Comment: @KevinDanikowski If you need anything just ask, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Hey @kakamg0, I keep receiving 'Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.' due to adding the code  `if (allParametersQuery.allParameters && (!allParametersQuery.allParameters.loading && !allParametersQuery.allParameters.error))
        terms= allParametersQuery.allParameters.map((parameter) => {return  '{{' + parameter.param + '}}'})` , I set allParametersQuery to be what I passed to this component through `terms`. Any idea why this map is causing this issue?

Comment: I think the warning is coming from the `result` array in the `Highlighter` component, you should change `result.push(<span className="highlighted">{str}</span>);` to `result.push(<span key={match.index} className="highlighted">{str}</span>);`. You can read more about the warning [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys)

Comment: you're a genius thank you! match.index gave duplicate keys, I used message.length. Works well enough without giving errors.

Answer (score 1):

use `Array#map` to extract values for wrapping in `<span>` and then cycle on them for replacement:

```js
let string = 'this is a message with many inputs, {{input1}}, {{input2}}, and again {{input1}}';
let array = [{parameter: '{{input1}}'},{parameter: '{{input2}}'}];

array.map(el => { return el.parameter }).forEach(str => {
  string = string.split(str).join("<span className=\'bizarre-highlight\'>" + str + "</span>");
});
    
console.log(string);
```

Comment: This worked and replaced what I needed. Thank you! it didn't solve my issue of adding CSS to the text, but I should be on the right path now.

Comment: @KevinDanikowski why not add style attribute to span?

Comment: to be honest I don't know how that would change it or what exactly you mean. Right now I'm trying to figure a way to get the spans out of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a RegExp to  find all instances of '{{inputX}}', and wrap the matches with the `span`:

```js
const string = 'this is a message with many inputs, {{input1}}, {{input2}}, and again {{input3}}'

const array = [{parameter: '{{input1}}'},{parameter: '{{input2}}'}]

const pattern = new RegExp(array.map(({ parameter }) => parameter).join('|'), 'g');

const result = string.replace(pattern, (match) => 
  `<span className='bizarre-highlight'>${match}</span>`
)

console.log(result)
```